# Why component doesn't update when received data? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component where I try to show single post in my blog app. when I come from index page everything works fine. But when I put url of post and go directly to that path (for example `/posts/2357`), there is a problem. In my code inspector, on Network tab I can see data of this post but for some reason component doesn't update and user see only endless "Loading..." component.

My component:

```
class PostsShow extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.props.post) {
            const { id } = this.props.match.params;
            this.props.fetchPost(id);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { post } = this.props;
    // Check if we already have a post
        if (!post) {
            return <Loader />;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row m-t-2">
                    <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                    <span className="m-b-2 label label-info">{post.categories}</span>
                    <p>{post.content}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
     }
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) {
    return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPost })(PostsShow);
```

Action:

```
export function fetchPost(id) {
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`);

    return {
        type: FETCH_POST,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST:
        return { ...state, [action.payload.data]: action.payload.data  };
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: In mapStateToProps, did you checked the `posts` ?Is it having the data?Also please share the action and reducers where you dispatching action and data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is wrong in your reducer. You set the object key of your state to `[action.payload.data]` and also set the value of this object to `[action.payload.data]`. Shouldn't you set the key value to `[action.payload.data.id]`?